# GCD Not Executing In Block Order

Tags: swift, firebase, grand-central-dispatch, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check from my Firebase Database if certain nodes exist, and if not, create new ones in the Database. I need my method `loadAll()` to fully execute before it calls a second method that creates any missing nodes `autoCheck`. I tried a dispatch group to do this, but it doesn't work, `print("Done downloading!")` is called before it is done checking the database. Thanks!!

Code:

```
func loadAll(){
    var deleted_load = false
    var poor_load = false
    var allLoadDone = false

    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
        let uid = user.uid

        let refff = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        let userRef = refff.childByAppendingPath("users/\(uid)")


        //When making new fields increase this var
        var howmany = 2
        var done = 0

        var downloadGroup = dispatch_group_create()
        dispatch_group_enter(downloadGroup)
        userRef.queryOrderedByValue().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            allLoadDone = true
            if(!snapshot.exists()){
                print("ERR DOES NOT EXCIST")
                self.autoCheck(deleted_load, poor_load: poor_load, userRef: userRef, ig: 1)
                return
            }
            if let score = snapshot.value as? Int {
                if(snapshot.key=="deleted"){
                    deleted_load = true
                }
                if(snapshot.key=="Staff_Poor"){
                    poor_load = true
                }
                print("\(snapshot.key) is \(score)")
                self.counter.text = String(score)
            }
            done = done + 1
            if(done>=(howmany)){
                self.autoCheck(deleted_load, poor_load: poor_load, userRef: userRef, ig: 2)
            }
        })
            dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)

        dispatch_group_notify(downloadGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // 2
            print("Done downloading!")
        }
    } else {
        print("No user!")
        gotoLogin()
    }
}

func autoCheck(deleted_load: Bool, poor_load: Bool, userRef: FIRDatabaseReference, ig: Int) -> Bool{
    print("ID IS: \(ig)")
    var newUserData = ["deleted": 0, "Staff_Poor": 0]
    print("deleted_load: \(deleted_load)")
    if deleted_load==true{
        newUserData.removeValueForKey("deleted")
    }
    print("poor_load: \(poor_load)")
    if poor_load==true{
        newUserData.removeValueForKey("Staff_Poor")
    }
    if(!newUserData.isEmpty){
        userRef.updateChildValues(newUserData)
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `dispatch_group_leave(downloadGroup)` must be placed inside the completion handler closure. Right now, you have it outside, which means that the group will be finished before the asynchronous calls are done.

But let's step back and understand the purpose of dispatch groups. The typical pattern is to use dispatch group when you're performing a whole series of asynchronous tasks, and you want to know when they're all done. So, for each task, you enter the group before invoking some asynchronous process, and then leave the group within the completion handler of that asynchronous process, something like:

```
let group = dispatch_group_create()

for object in arrayOfObjects {
    dispatch_group_enter(group)
    performSomeAsynchronousActionWithObject(object) { result in 
        // do something with `result`
        ...
        dispatch_group_leave(group)
    }
}

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    print("done performing asynchronous task with all of those objects")
}
```

---

Frankly, the use of dispatch group might not be appropriate here. The concept with dispatch groups that every "enter" is matched by a corresponding "leave". You're calling "enter" once, but it's not clear that you have any assurances how many times the observer will ultimately get called.

But in this case, you're dealing with an "observer", some block of code that will be called, however many times the event takes place. It may not take place at all. It might take place many times. It's just a question of how many times the observed event takes place.

Now, if you know with certainty that this will be called once and only once, then technically this pattern would work. But if it's getting called once and only once, you don't really need a dispatch group at all.

Comment: Hey I have another question, for some reason if the user is not in my Database, (for example if it is a new user) `userRef.queryOrderedByValue().observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in` does not execute. Am I doing something wrong or is that how Firebase works?

Comment: I'm no expert in Firebase, but with an observer pattern, that closure would generally get called however many times that `.ChildAdded` event is triggered. Do you have assurances as to how many times that event is triggered?

Comment: The `.ChildAdded` event is triggered once. I ran the app twice, once with the `users/<user_uid>` existing in my database and once with `users/<user_uid>` removed from my database. With `users/<user_uid>` existing, the `.ChildAdded` event was triggered, however the second time it failed to trigger. @Rob

Comment: If I'm following you, sometimes the observer is called and sometimes its not. Then the dispatch group pattern probably doesn't make sense. It only makes sense if you know that each "enter" will be matched with exactly one (not zero, not multiple) "leaves".

Comment: That's correct. However, I want the event triggered each time, why does it not trigger when I remove `users/<user_uid>` from the database? @Rob

Comment: I assume there's a different `.ChildRemoved` event.

Comment: umm do I need a `.ChildRemoved` event? (Sorry I'm familiar with multiple threads in Java, but I'm fairly new to Swift Threading) @Rob

Comment: See the "Child events" section of [Retrieve Data on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data). They illustrate adding observers for both `.ChildAdded` and `.ChildRemoved`.